# Create ethereum address from seed

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I want to create ethereum address from seed.

Please help me to create ethereum address from seed.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific here. What seed? Is this related to Geth? Is this related to Android?

Comment: 24 word mnemonic seed which are used to create address of bitcoin.

Comment: Like 
rude mom curtain task miss range sample carry gallery alley hundred pledge gravity episode easy absurd dove market exile flash ignore fence omit erupt

Comment: Hi there. Was that just an example mnemonic, or one you've used in the past...? Either way, now that you've made it public, I'd suggest generating a new one. (And taking any other necessary security precautions.)

Comment: the bitcoin addresses generated from mnemionic seeds where hacked and all funds were stolen. Read this story before you want to mess with this method of generating an address: https://medium.com/@touchdownFW/an-alternative-approach-to-cold-private-key-storage-on-a-flash-drive-using-uuid-4da38cd4fb34   , trully random number generation offered in `geth` is much better. And all you have to do is to back it up well.

Answer (score 3):

You can create them manually by going to [this site](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/?), insert your words into the `BIP39 Mnemonic` field and choose ETH from the `Coin` field. The web page will generate a bunch of addresses in order.

**Warning:** only use online tools for testing purposes, not with your real seed words, or you might lose your crypto!

If you want to generate them programatically, there are open source libraries that should work. Although I haven't tried it, [this eth-hd-wallet javascript library](https://github.com/meth/eth-hd-wallet) seems to be capable of doing it.

Comment: What If I want to use geth.aar for android and want to generate same address every time from 24 words seed?
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

First use Ethers.js to convert seed phrase into private key using this method: `ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic('Seed phrase here')`.

Afterwards use `web3.js` to discover address from private key using this method: `web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web tool like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) or a browser plugin like [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) to turn your 24 word mnemonic seed into an accessible Ethereum account.

Comment: What If I want to use geth.aar for android and want to generate same address every time from 24 words seed?
Please help me with this.