# insufficient gas funds error on rinkeby infura using brownie

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3.py, brownie, chainlink

I have sufficient ether in my testnet account but still the code is showing error. What to do next? I have attached multiple screenshots of my code and metamask rinkeby wallet.. Kindly guide me[image]

[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Comu3.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Majd TL's helpful observation there, if you'd like to see the various ethereum addresses that get generated from your mnemonic (aka seed phrase) take a look at the answer to this post on how to ["Create ethereum  address from seed"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51196/create-ethereum-address-from-seed).

Please pay special attention to the Warning in the answer because you should not share the seed phrase for your ethereum wallet as anyone can access your funds.

Answer (score 0):

Your mnemonic does not generate your metamask account that start with `0x76B...`

[image]